# How are $\rho$ and $u$ related with $w$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In the article *Stability of Rarefaction Waves to the 1D
Compressible Navier–Stokes Equations
with Density-Dependent Viscosity*, It says the solution of Burgers equation has the following properties listed in Lemma 2.1.
[image]
Then they define the 2-rarefaction wave as follows.
[image]

where the $\lambda_2$ is a eigenvalue.
[image]
where

[image]

Then they get the conclusion that
[image]

It seems that the conclusion is got from the properties of $w$. But how are $\rho,u$ related with $w$?